# Скачать файл c cайта

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvc, изображения

В результате моего Post метода на странице выводится изображение. Как в представлении и контроллере мне создать кнопку "Скачать" , чтобы при ее нажатии - это изображение загружалось на компьютер пользователя?
Так я вывожу это изображение на странице:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Files/"+ Model.ImageName)" alt="my image" />
```

Comment: Сервер какой, IIS? Доступ к его настройке имеется? Чтобы отправить файл на принудительное скачивание, его нужно отдавать с заголовком `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка скачать должна делать запрос на метод контроллера приблизительно следующего вида:

```
public ActionResult Image()
{
    var imageName = "someImage.jpg"
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Images"); // путь к папке с  изображениями
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, imageName); 
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```